# Rails best way to create large CSV file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

What is the best way to create a large CSV file.

I have a XML file I have parsed with nokogiri, now I need to generate a CSV file I will use for importing products to Magento. There is like 40 columns and I only need to fill out about 10 columns.

My ugly solution:

```
  require 'nokogiri'    
  csv_text = File.open("#{Dir.pwd}/app/controllers/ps_product.xml")
  @csv = Nokogiri::XML.parse(csv_text)
  CSV.open("#{Dir.pwd}/app/controllers/super.csv", "w+") do |csv|
    csv << [%q(sku,_store,_attribute_set,_type,_category,_root_category,_product_websites,color,cost,description,length,meta_description,meta_keyword,meta_title,name,price,short_description,status,url_key,visibility,weight,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,_links_related_sku,_links_related_position,_links_crosssell_sku,_links_crosssell_position,_links_upsell_sku,_links_upsell_position,_associated_sku,_associated_default_qty,_associated_position,_tier_price_website,_tier_price_customer_group,_tier_price_qty,_tier_price_price,_group_price_website,_group_price_customer_group,_group_price_price,_media_attribute_id,_media_image,_media_lable,_media_position,_media_is_disabled)]
    @csv.xpath("//table").each do |produkt|
    text = produkt.xpath('*[@name="reference"]').text        + ',,"Hair extensions ",simple,"","Default Category",base,"Sort, farve nr. 1",,'
             produkt.xpath('*[@name="description"]').text    + ',"65 cm",'
             produkt.xpath('*[@name="meta_description"]').text  + ','
             produkt.xpath('*[@name="meta_keywords"]').text    + ','
             produkt.xpath('*[@name="meta_title"]').text       + ','
             produkt.xpath('*[@name="name"]').text           + ','
             produkt.xpath('*[@name="price"]').text         + ','
             produkt.xpath('*[@name="short_description"]').text + ',1,'
             produkt.xpath('*[@name="link_rewrite"]').text      + ',4,'
             produkt.xpath('*[@name="weight"]').text            + ','
             produkt.xpath('*[@name="quanity"]').text + ',0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,0,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,88,,,1,0'
    csv << text 
  end
```

I think is code is bad and a mesh.

Comment: Going to try CSV builder.

Comment: There is nothing bad. It's a trivial task -- join columns one by one into string and store it in file.

Comment: Using the Gsub method could also make it more pretty.